# How to explicitly set marker IDs

Tags: xamarin.android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to set IDs of the markers that I show on the map. For instance, when I show four markers, I want to give them IDs 10, 20, 30 and 40 explicitly. Now they get m0, m1, m2 and m3. By the way, I need this so that when I click on the Info Window of any of these markers, I get the ID and know which marker's Info Window is clicked and that way I can use that ID (e.g. show it in a toast message for now).

Thanks.

Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set the marker-IDs on your own. But the method addMarker returns the marker with its ID set.

When later on the marker is clicked, the ID will be the same.

So you need to keep track of the IDs and the corresponding objects the markers stand for on your own e.g. by maintaining a map of marker IDs and objects, where you add a new item after each call of addMarker.